# From a selected line in a chart, filter a table or pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am facing a challenge. In a chart with multiple lines, I would like to able when I click on a line or mouse over a line to see the corresponding datapoint in the the table or pivot table...So basically, filtering a table based on the element i click or select on a chart with my mouse.

Do you think that it is achievable ? What would be the methodology ? Is there a VBA code for this ? I have seen examples, but they are working on the oppiste way; click or mouse over an observation and the line is highlighted...

Thanks in advance

saskap

Answer (score 0):

This is really complicated, you have to customize the code for each chart, this example code can be a starting point:

```
Dim p As Series
Dim pc As Long
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ch As ChartObject: Set ch = Me.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    With ch
        Dim s As Series: Set s = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next: Set s = .Chart.SeriesCollection(Target.Value): On Error GoTo 0
        If Not p Is Nothing And Not p Is s Then
            p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = pc
        End If
        If Not s Is Nothing Then
            Set p = s
            pc = s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            With s
                s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

- The first two rows are global variables that store which Series
  object was highlighted last time and what was its original color,
  this is needed to restore the original color when a different cell is
  selected. Unfortunately global variables in VBA loose their value when the project is reset (e.g. the Stop button is pressed or an error occurs), so it is possible that this code colors a bar and then cannot color it back. If important, these information may be stored in invisible Cells or Chart data but that complicates the code.
- The next line means that this is an event handler, a function that is called in response to a certain event, in this case when the selection changes on a certain worksheet (the one on which you insert this - you have to insert this into a worksheet module not a standard code module).
- Next we look up the chart based on its name and assign it to a variable, which is of type ChartObject, so early binding will allows us to depend on the support of intellisense (if you type a . it shows members of interfaces).
- Then we look up the Series inside the chart based on the name found in the newly selected cell's contents. Since we don't know if the new cell will have a valid name, we have to protect this line with disabling error handling and checking later if the s has a non-nothing value. - This part depends largly on the type of chart and how it represents data, it is possible that you will have to select data based on Series::XValues.
- We check if there is a saved value for a previously highlighted bar and if it is different from the current selection, restore its original color.
- Finally if the looking up the Series earlier was successful then s is non-null and we save the color of the current bar and highlight it with red fill.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to do it for one graph. Could explain me what your code is doing ?

Comment: Thanks. I have copy pasted the code nothing happened. I mean, when i click on the Macro icon under view ribon, the macro doesn't appear, has this macro a name ? What I have done is ALT F11 and then inserted a new module and then paste the code in that module....

Comment: The name is Worksheet_SelectionChange but it is not shown in the dialog since it is not explicitly called by the user but the Excel calls it whenever the user selects a different cell. Try setting a breakpoint at Dim ch, and click on a cell in Excel.